# MySQL connection closed in Play! Framework

Tags: java, mysql, playframework, java-8

My play! framework app throws an exception saying

> The last packet successfully received from the server was 71,930,591
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was
>   71,930,592 milliseconds ago. is longer than the server configured
>   value of 'wait_timeout'. You should consider either expiring and/or
>   testing connection validity before use in your application, increasing
>   the server configured values for client timeouts, or using the
>   Connector/J connection property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid this
>   problem.

My Connection url is

> default.url="jdbc:mysql://{host}:{port}/{schema}?autoreconnect=true&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true"

Play! Framework version 2.5.14
JAVA 8

Comment: what database pool are you using? that's not a Play Framework exception.

Comment: Default database pool.

Comment: I was thinking to use a database pool cause from long back I'm seeing the same problem with play framework's default database pool.

Comment: I have no used Play, *but* there could be some settings that you need to enable for this error to go away.

Comment: can you please suggest a database pool for java.

Comment: my all time favorite: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP

Comment: Thank You!! :)
can we implement this with multiple shards as well?

Comment: I have no idea... you will have to play with that yourself ;)

Comment: That's great.... Thanks!!

Comment: As I can see 

# The combination of these two settings results in "db.default" as the
  # default JDBC pool:
  #config = "db"
  #default = "default"

  # Play uses HikariCP as the default connection pool.  You can override
  # settings by changing the prototype:
  prototype {
    # Sets a fixed JDBC connection pool size of 50
    #hikaricp.minimumIdle = 50
    #hikaricp.maximumPoolSize = 50
  }